# How to install MongoDB 5.0.3 on Linux Mint 19+

Tags: mongodb, linux-mint

I want to install MongoDB 5.0.3 on Linux Mint 19.3.

I use these instructions which work on Ubuntu 20.04:

- `wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add`
- `sudo apt-get install gnupg`
- `echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

However, even after installing this, I cannot start the Mongo daemon with `sudo systemctl start mongod` (error: mongod.service not found).

And when I start `mongo`, it shows an older version:

[image]

How can I install MongoDB 5.0.3 on Linux Mint 19?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3027266

Comment: Did you start `mongod` manually?

Comment: On Ubuntu I start mongod with `sudo systemctl start mongod` but on Mint I get `(error: mongod.service not found)`. I read that Mint 19+ apparently has MongoDB pre-installed, so I tried to deinstall it with `sudo systemctl stop mongod` etc. but I get the same error. So it seems to be installed in some other way than how I installed it on Ubuntu.

Comment: Sometimes the service is named `mongdb` or just `mongo`. Otherwise create the service file manually.

Comment: You're right, `sudo systemctl start mongodb` starts the service, but when I type `mongo` then, it comes up as v3.6.3 again. So I remove it with `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*` etc. and reinstall it as I do on Ubuntu, but the command `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org` returns: `Error: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation, mogodb-org-database is required but is not going to be installed`.

Comment: What about `sudo apt-get purge mongo*`?

Comment: Yes, with `sudo apt-get purge mongo*` it seems to delete the current Mongo instance, but then installing as on Ubuntu, I get the error:  *Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following packages have unmet dependencies:  mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-database but it is not going to be installed. Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.*

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=5.0.3 mongodb-org-database=5.0.3 mongodb-org-server=5.0.3 mongodb-org-shell=5.0.3 mongodb-org-mongos=5.0.3 mongodb-org-tools=5.0.3`?

Comment: Unfortnately, `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=5.0.3` gives me the same I get the error: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following packages have unmet dependencies: mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-database but it is not going to be installed. Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: I have Linux Mint 19.3, could that me a factor?

Comment: No idea, I work only with Redhat.

Answer (score 1):

Linux Mint 19.3 is based on Ubuntu Bionic (18.04), not Focal (20.04). That is probably why you are having issues.  Select the command for the bionic install.  See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

A Mint installation is based on a Ubuntu version. As Andrea suggested you need to use the correct MongoDB repositories for your installation. The version of Ubuntu can be parsed from `/etc/os-release`.

Here is an example for installing MongoDB-5 in Mint

```
curl -sS https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-5.0.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor --output /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mongodb-org-5.0-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu $(. /etc/os-release; echo "$UBUNTU_CODENAME")/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```